# Sequential Firebase data into a difference data structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem that I'm retrieving a sequential list (event_*xx*) from a Firebase database that has a different structure to the class I've declared the structure in.

The class which defines my data structure has two fields; event and icon, both declared as String types and the database structure is event_01, event_02, icon_01, etc.... the suffix is because there are multiple events / icons.

So when I return the data from the database the object doesn't match the class structure and everything is NULL.

Is there a way to change the data in the datasnapshot so that I can remove the suffix of xxxx_01, _02, etc... before it gets added to the array? As the array doesn't care about duplucate key names.

Here is my code;

```
aIHList.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            asItHappened_List aIH = dataSnapshot.getValue(asItHappened_List.class);
            aIHList.add(aIH);
        }
        asItHappened adapter = new asItHappened(getActivity(), aIHList);
        aIHResult.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The data structure is simple;

```
public class asItHappened_List {

String event;
String icon;

public asItHappened_List() {

}

public asItHappened_List(String event, String icon) {
    this.event = event;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

}
```

The database structure looks like;

```
Root
 -AsItHappened
  -- Match_01
   --- event_01
   --- icon_01
   --- event_02
   --- icon_02
  -- Match_02
   --- event_01
   --- icon_01
```

Comment: Please share your database structure to see it more clearly.

Comment: Updated to include the database structure